# keyerror in python table

Tags: python

I'm confused about the code below:

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    def add(self, row, col, val):
        self.d[row][col] = val
    def get(self, row, col, default=None):
        return self.d[row].get(col, default)
    def incol(self, col, val):
        for x,y in self.d.iteritems():
            if y[col]==val:
                wholerow=y
        return wholerow.values()
```

After I created table, I cannot use the "incol" function to get all the values. It always give me key error. However, when I just use the same code without using function, I can get what I want. What happened to my code....

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: How are you calling the method? What does it mean "when I just use the same code without using function"?

Comment: Seems to me that you are assuming `y[col]` will exist, but `y` is regular dictionary. Try `y.get(col) == val` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not "always give me key error" ("always" being the word I am disputing here). For example, consider the following code:

```
foo = Table()
foo.add("row_1", "col_1", "col_1_value")
foo.add("row_1", "col_2", "col_2_value")
print foo.get("row_1", "col_1")
print foo.incol("col_1", "col_1_value")
```

This works without any errors and produces the following output:

```
col_1_value
['col_2_value', 'col_1_value']
```

However, if you try to pass the name of a non-existent column to `incol`, you will get a `KeyError`. For example, if you append the following line to the above code:

```
print foo.incol("i do not exist", "my imaginary value")
```

You will end up with an error message resembling the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./stack_overflow-2013-03-14.py", line 21, in <module>
    print foo.incol("i do not exist", "my imaginary value")
File "./stack_overflow-2013-03-14.py", line 12, in incol
    if y[col]==val:
KeyError: 'i do not exist'
```

An example implementation of `incol` that can handle such situations is:

```
def incol(self, col, val):
    result = None
    for x,y in self.d.iteritems():
        if col in y and y[col]==val:
            result = y.values()
            break
    return result
```

Now, if you run the following lines:

```
foo = Table()
foo.add("row_1", "col_1", "col_1_value")
foo.add("row_1", "col_2", "col_2_value")
print foo.get("row_1", "col_1")
print foo.incol("col_1", "col_1_value")
print foo.incol("i do not exist", "my imaginary value")
print foo.incol("i do not exist", None)
```

You get:

```
col_1_value
['col_2_value', 'col_1_value']
None
None
```

You can also use the following implementation of `incol` as suggested by Martijn Pieters:

```
def incol(self, col, val):
    result = None
    for x,y in self.d.iteritems():
        if y.get(col)==val:
            result = y.values()
            break
    return result
```

But in this case if you pass a non-existent `col` name and `val`=`None`, then it will match any row. The corresponding output will be:

```
col_1_value
['col_2_value', 'col_1_value']
None
['col_2_value', 'col_1_value']
```

Maybe this is the behavior you want for your application. That is for you to decide.